# Change color of forest nodes

Tags: color, forest

I'm trying to change the color of certain blocks to green and some to red in a forest graph in LaTeX using Overleaf. I'm not getting anywhere though. My current code is:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={shadow xshift=5pt,shadow yshift=-5pt}}
\begin{figure}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={font=\sffamily, rounded corners, top color=gray!5, bottom color=gray!10, edge+={darkgray, line width=1pt}, draw=darkgray, align=center, anchor=children},
  before packing={where n children=3{calign child=2, calign=child edge}{}},
  before typesetting nodes={where content={}{coordinate}{}},
  where level<=1{line width=2pt}{line width=1pt},
  [\textbf{220 TLD glow curves}\\, blur shadow
    [\textbf{Cluster 0}\\185

    [\textbf{Cluster 0.0}\\158]
        [
          [\textbf{Cluster 0.2}\\5]
          [
            [\textbf{Outlier 0.4}\\6]
          ]
          [\textbf{Outlier 0.3}\\8]
        ]
        [\textbf{Cluster 0.1}\\8]
      ]
    
    [\textbf{Cluster 1}\\10]
    [\textbf{Cluster 2}\\3]
          [\textbf{Cluster 3}\\5]
            [\textbf{Cluster 4}\\5]
          [\textbf{Outlier -1}\\12]
       
      ]

\end{forest}
\caption{\label{tab:table-1}Tree graph representing final classification of all TLD glow curves.}
\end{figure}
```

Which returns:

[image]

I would like to change blocks Cluster 0.0, 0.1 and 0.2 to green and the rest to red (except 220 TL glow curves and Cluster 0, leaving it grey).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Please try to copy and compile your code snippet. Then add the missing parts until it compiles. That‘s the code we‘d like to see here, as it also provides information from your preamble.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what you mean. My code compiles fine in Overleaf and it shows the image I attached to the post. (it does give 'runaway argument errors' but it shows how I want it to in the display, and since I do not know where the errors are I leave it how it is ). I did though edit and added the package at the beginning of the code in this post, if that is what you mean

Comment: When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Thanks @SandyG , better, but still does not compile for me. It's missing documentclass, begin and end, and it might have some problems inside the forest statements.

Answer (score 4):

- Your code fragment contain numbers of errors. For example: empty lines in fined tree code, not defined
- Please always check code before show it in question

The simplest way to change color of some articular nodes is add option for colors to this node. For example

```
[\textbf{Cluster 1}\\10, draw=green, top color=green!5, bottom color=green!30]
```

AN example of corrected your code fragment and completed to small document MWE (Minimal Working Example) is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                shadows, shadows.blur}

\tikzset{every shadow/.style={shadow xshift=5pt,shadow yshift=-5pt}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree = {
    rounded corners, 
    top color=gray!5, bottom color=gray!30, 
    edge+={darkgray, line width=1pt}, 
    draw=darkgray, 
    align=center, 
    anchor=children,
    l sep=7mm,
    fork sep = 4mm
            },
before packing = {where n children=3{calign child=2, calign=child edge}{}},
before typesetting nodes={where content={}{coordinate}{}},
where level<=1{line width=2pt}{line width=1pt},
[\textbf{220 TLD glow curves}\\, blur shadow
    [\textbf{Cluster 0}\\185
        [\textbf{Cluster 0.0}\\158]
            [
                [\textbf{Cluster 0.2}\\5]
                    [
                        [\textbf{Outlier 0.4}\\6]
                    ]
                [\textbf{Outlier 0.3}\\8]
            ]
        [\textbf{Cluster 0.1}\\8]
    ]
    [\textbf{Cluster 1}\\10, draw=green, top color=green!5, bottom color=green!30]
    [\textbf{Cluster 2}\\3, draw=red, top color=red!5, bottom color=red!30,]
          [\textbf{Cluster 3}\\5]
            [\textbf{Cluster 4}\\5]
          [\textbf{Outlier -1}\\12]
      ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: That is exactly what I was after!! Thank you very much! I will take into acount the MWE for next time, I am new to this forum, sorry.

Comment: @Danny, since answer solve your problem, you ma consider to accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) and also award it with voting it by click on up-triangle at the same place.